# reading japanese text from json: wrong characters

Tags: java, json, selenium, utf-8

I have a ja.json file which contains key value pairs for selenium framework :

"key": [ "私はあなたを愛しています！",

I have saved the file as UTF-8 format.But when I am trying to read values from json, I am getting string as "?????"

I am using below code:

```
  Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(filePath));
  JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
  String text= (String) jsonObject.get(key);
  String expectedValue = new String(text.getBytes("UTF-8"),"UTF-8");
```

What else can I do to get japanese characters from a JSON file(or any other format if required) and send ?

Comment: `FileReader` uses default platform encoding which often is not UTF-8. Instead you can use something like `new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath), "UTF-8")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the file with the correct charset, for example:

```
Object obj = parser.parse(new InputStreamReader(
    new FileInputStream(filePath), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

The `FileReader` will use the platform encoding whatever that is on your system.

Any attempt to repair the encoding after reading the file with the wrong encoding will fail. So your line

```
String expectedValue = new String(text.getBytes("UTF-8"),"UTF-8");
```

is useless.